# Нет ssms.exe, после установки SQL Server Management Studio. Откуда найти и как правильно установить?

Tags: sql, sql-server, сервер, ssms

После установки SQL Server Management Studio 18 нет самого приложения ssms.exe. Поискал по этому пути: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE и ничего не нашел. Программа после установки не добавилось и в меню пуск (понятное дело, что если даже будет то не заработает т.к отсутствует главная программа по главному пути).
Проблема появилось после удаления и повторной установки программы. Установил программу и на другие диски, но и там не устанавливается (ssms.exe).
Как быть? Может кто-то знаете как исправить или хотя-бы откуда скачать сам ярлык?

Comment: правильную версию выбрали для своей ОС? кстати на каком windows вы устанавливаете? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: windows 10 pro 64bit с последними обновлениями. Но дело не в этом устанавливаю я правильную. Раньше всё было ок. Но после удаления и повторной установки не устанавливается ярлык ssms.exe в самой папке

Comment: после деинсталяции mssms удалите принудительно ключ из реестра: reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32

Comment: и если осталась папка C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\ то её так же надо удалить

Comment: Из регистра давно удалил и папки очистил но не помогло :( А если кто-нибудь отправит только сам ssms.exe и я закину его в папку с программой то поможет?

Answer (score 0):

Врываюсь в тему с ноги.

У меня началась подобная печалька. Решила называется обновить. Ходила по форумам ответов - ноль. Все всё решили и никак не отписали, видимо. Либо снесли ssms к кочерыжкам хыхы

Решение проблемы нетривиальное. Эта "радость" у меня не удалялась и не загружалась. Понесла свою тушку в реестр и запись в реестре переименовала. На Компьютер\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\ Old Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
Папку в програм файлс переименовала так же (со словом олД). (Я ничего не удаляла)

Затем запустила загрузчик и пошла загрузка. Загрузилось создав новую пупку "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" криво без некоторых файлов, в тч БЕЗ ssms.exe.
Объединила папки (в новую скопипастила всё из старой, которая с припиской олд) - всё работает.

Ставьте стрелку вверх кому помогло, шоб не зря писала.